# Possible to slice to MIDI *manually* in Ableton?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

Is it possible to slice to MIDI **manually** in Ableton?

Most people just use the [slice-to-MIDI](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/converting-audio-to-midi/#11-1-slice-to-new-midi-track) feature (right click on clip and Ableton more or less does the rest), but I want to know if it's even possible to slice audio to MIDI w/ out the built-in feature.

The motivation for this question is that I'm using Ableton Lite and [slice-to-MIDI is not available for Lite (or Intro)](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/converting-audio-to-midi/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can do this, in fact it's a very common industry practice, and is often called "sampling."

When sampling, you create a sample (smaller audio clip) of the clip, which you can then load into a sampler instrument in Ableton and play back by triggering the instrument.

The samplers included in Ableton (Sampler and Simpler) offer the ability to pitch-shift the sampled clip by playing differently-pitched notes. But by loading a sampler into an instrument rack and defining which keys will trigger it, you can "chain" multiple samplers together into one piano roll, then create MIDI data to trigger them in whatever order you'd like.